# How to fix: Angular / Ionic v4 "Can't find stylesheet to import" from library in monorepo project

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ionic4, node-sass, ionic-cli

I have a monorepo project that includes a library, several projects, and the main project. My ionic project is in the `projects` folder.

I cannot build my ionic project (`ionic build` or `ng build`) because it imports a module from the main project (`src/`) which imports a sass file from a third project in the `libs/` folder.

When building with `ionic build`, I get the error:

"Can't find stylesheet to import."

`@import 'libs/...';`

When I build with the ng-cli, I get errors for each of the references to sass files imported from `libs/...` seemingly everywhere in the project, even files/modules that aren't imported in this project.

I don't have any issue building other projects that import from the folder.

The `package.json` file inside of the ionic project folder includes this snippet:

```
"config": {
    "ionic_webpack": "./webpack.config.js",
    "ionic_sass": "./sass.config.js",
    "ionic_source_map_type": "source-map"
  },
```

My custom config is pasted below, I've tried variations of including `../../` or not and running `ionic build` from both the root directory and the project root:

```
const useDefaultConfig = require('@ionic/app-scripts/config/sass.config.js');

useDefaultConfig.includePaths.push('libs/path/to/assets/scss');
useDefaultConfig.includePaths.push('libs/path/to/assets/scss/partials');
useDefaultConfig.includePaths.push('../../libs/path/to/assets/scss');
useDefaultConfig.includePaths.push('../../libs/path/to/assets/scss/partials');

useDefaultConfig.includePaths.push('dist/path/to/assets/scss');
useDefaultConfig.includePaths.push('dist/path/to/assets/scss/partials');
useDefaultConfig.includePaths.push('../../dist/path/to/assets/scss');
useDefaultConfig.includePaths.push('../../dist/path/to/assets/scss/partials');

module.exports = useDefaultConfig;
```

I also tried doing

```
module.exports = function(){ return useDefualtConfig; };
```

I added paths to the `stylePreprocessorOptions.includePaths` in the project's section of the `angular.json` file like so:

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
    "includePaths": [
        "libs/path",
        "libs/path/assets/scss",
        "libs/path/assets/scss/partials",
        "dist/path",
        "dist/path/assets/scss",
        "dist/path/assets/scss/partials"
    ]
},
```

I also included the paths in both `tsconfig.app.json` and `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm facing the same problem.